# link_to link unresponsive on page with no errors, rendered fine

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I'm working with Rails 4.1.4.

I have a series of links within a certain section of my main page that are rendering fine but are completely unresponsive, with no error message of any sort. The page:

main/index.html.haml:

```
.container.main
  %h4 Featured Video
    .featured
      = render partial: 'main/video', locals: {video: @featured}
```

@featured is determined in main_controller.rb:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @featured = Video.all.sample(1)[0]
  end
end
```

And the video is rendered in _video.html.haml:

```
.video-head
  = link_to "#{video.event.conference.name} #{video.event.name_suffix}", video.event
.video-show

  - if video.youtube_code
    .embed-container
      = embed(video.youtube_code)
.video-stats
  .video-title
    = link_to video.title, video_path(video)
    - if user_signed_in? && current_user.role == 'admin'
      = link_to edit_admin_video_path(video) do 
        %i.fa.fa-pencil.small
  %br
  .video-presenters
    = raw display_linked_presenters(video)

  .small.video-license
    = render "videos/license", video: video

  .video-abstract
    = raw video.abstract

  .small-info
    Rated:
    = video.rating
    %br
    Views:
    %strong
      = count_views(video)
```

All of this renders fine. When I go to the page at localhost, all links within the class .video-stats are completely unresponsive. I can go to the inspect element in Chrome and find the rendered html:

```
<div class="video-stats">
  <div class="video-title">
    <a href="/videos/24">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    <a href="/admin/videos/24/edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil small"></i></a>
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="video-presenters">
    <a href="/presenters/4">Laura Fields</a>
  </div>
  <div class="small video-license">
    <div xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#">
      This presentation, by
      <a href="/presenters/4">Laura Fields</a>,
      is licensed under a
      <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" rel="license" target="_blank">Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike 3.0</a>
      <br>
      <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" rel="license">
        <img alt="80x15" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/3.0/80x15.png">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="video-abstract">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="small-info">
    Rated:
      Everyone
    <br>
    Views:
    <strong>
      7
    </strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if I click the links within the inspect element html page, they work fine. I've managed to suss out that this may be some kind of JavaScript problem? But I'm not using any JavaScript on this page, and all of the links on the page OUTSIDE of that class work fine. So perhaps it has something to do with the iframe element. But I haven't been able to find anything about iframe elements disrupting links and don't know how to solve this.

The video is rendered with the following helper method:

```
def embed(youtube_code)
  content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_code}")
end
```

I believe that all my required JavaScript files are in the right order in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .
```

I think it's worth noting that I use this same partial in the video show page as well, and it has the same problem. :/ I'm tagging this as CSS because I think it MAY have something to do with z-index (.embed-container takes up the space that .video-stats does when I highlight it with Chrome Dev Tools). Even still, I don't know how to go about fixing that.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you tried removing the .embed container? In the web inspector highlight the embed container and hit delete on your keyboard to remove the element. See if the links work after that.

Comment: That fixes it, yup. Causes a whole ton of formatting issues, but that shouldn't be difficult to fix. Thank you! Can you explain why you thought of this/what the .embed container was doing to cause this issue?

Comment: Actually... those formatting issues are pretty substantial. The css behind that embed-container was: .embed-container {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
} Without those rules, without something to hold the iframe element, I have no idea how to render the video properly.

Comment: Nevermind. Fixed those formatting issues - easier than I originally thought. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: That element was probably set to position: absolute or relative. So it was flowing above other elements and the click event only bubbles up not through stacked elements.